# LinkedIn authentication stopped returning formatted picture

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, linkedin-api

My app uses LinkedIn authentication along with a couple of other social network logins.

Even though authentication is working fine, all of a sudden LinkedIn stopped returning the formatted profile picture i.e. `picture-url`. I do however continue to receive the original image i.e. `picture-urls` -- see below:
[image]

In my authentication request, I request `r_basicprofile` and `r_emailaddress` and according to this link, I should be receiving both the formatted and the original image.
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

Up until 10 days ago or so, I was receiving both images. I didn't make any changes to my code but for some reason, the formatted image doesn't show up anymore. Any idea why and how to fix this?

UPDATE:
All of a sudden I started getting both images again -- without making any changes to my code.

I also noticed that the image URL has now changed and I'm seeing all types of parameters in there -- such as image size, something that looks like API version type (alpha in the example below) and possibly a time stamp indicator:

```
https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/{image-id}/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0?e=123456789&v=alpha&t={sometypeofid}
```

I don't remeber seeing any of these parameters in the image URL which is not a URL at all but what seems to be an API call that returns an image.

I don't know if LinkedIn announced such changes that I missed or just decided to make these changes without keeping developers in the loop. I hope it's not the latter and I simply missed the announcement.

Comment: Is this happening for every profile?

Comment: Hard to say because we're in beta so I can only see very limited data. However, it's happened to my account. I also see a similar post here on a similar issue. The only difference there is they were not getting the large image -- so the opposite of my issue. Nevertheless, there seems to be an issue where instead of getting two profile images, LinkedIn seems to be giving only one -- in my case, I get the original file uploaded but don't get the processed version. The other developer who posted here is getting the processed version but not the full image.

Comment: Yes, I saw that issue few days back. But I assume only LI support can give a good answer on this

Comment: I don't see LI support anywhere. They're pointing to StackOverflow - https://developer.linkedin.com/support